# How to generate an auth token and list out the resource groups in azure using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have tried with the below code:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import requests

subscription_id = 'MYSUBID'
client_id = 'MYCLIENTID'
client_secret = 'MYSECRETVALUE'
tenant_id = 'MYTENANTID'

# Create a ClientSecretCredential object
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01"
# Get an access token for the Azure Management API
access_token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default")


# Make the GET request to retrieve a list of resource groups
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    resource_groups = response.json()
    for rg in resource_groups['value']:
        print(rg['name'])
else:
    print(response.status_code, "-" ,response.text)
```

So this code gives me the below error:

403 - {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'f89e9744-3f48-444c-bf6f-525d15974a46' with object id 'f89e9744-3f48-444c-bf6f-525d15974a46' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over scope '/subscriptions/MYSUBID' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

But when I used this website to list it out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resource-groups/list?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0

It successfully lists the resource groups. Then I come to know that the bearer token or the auth token is different.

Help on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 403 - {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client
> 'f89e9744-3f48-44xxx' with object id 'f89e9744-3f48xxxx5974a46' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read'
> over scope '/subscriptions/MYSUBID' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

The above error tells us that your application doesn't have the proper permission or role to list the resource groups.

To list resource groups you need the **`Reader`** role. you can assign roles through the portal:

***Go to azure portal -> subscription -> Access control(IAM) -> Add -> Add Role assignments -> search (Reader role) -> select members (Your Application) -> click review + assign.***

[image]

After assigning roles I used the below code to get the list of resource groups.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import requests

subscription_id = 'xxx'
client_id = 'xxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxx'
tenant_id = 'xxxx'

# Create a ClientSecretCredential object
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01"
# Get an access token for the Azure Management API
access_token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default").token

# Make the GET request to retrieve a list of resource groups
h1 = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}
response = requests.get(url,headers=h1)

if response.status_code == 200:
    resource_groups = response.json()
    print(f"-----Resource Group Names------")
    for rg in resource_groups['value']:
        print(rg['name'])
else:
    print(response.status_code, "-" ,response.text)
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Resource Groups - List - REST API (Azure Resource Management) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resource-groups/list)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you tell me the way I am generating the auth token is valid? @Venkatesan

Comment: @Navi yeah it is valid.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check with the admin to provide the access and valid this again.